# TFS merge issues when converting CSS to LESS

Tags: tfs, less, web-essentials

As part of a branched project in TFS, I've converted our static CSS files to LESS files which dynamically creates CSS on save/compile using Visual Studio Web Essentials.

However I have concerns that when merging back up into the main branch TFS will try and merge the existing CSS files with the dynamic CSS files, rather than replacing the CSS files with the LESS files.

What is the best way of avoiding this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you checkin the newly generated files, they will be taken over by TFS as though you edited them yourself. Depending on your repository/workspace config, you may need to checkout the files first before regereration.

On the other hand, since the css files are now generated, you could remove them from TFS and exclude them from source control. 
The downside of this is that you need to regenerate the files whenever they are needed. It may not be practical in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommend to store generated files under source control. You can use .tfignore or .gitignore to tell VS to ignore the .css files in that folder and only track your .less files.

If you need the .css files then run the generation...